# persist data/text in a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

WeekViewTableCell.h:

```
 @interface WeekViewTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel         *textlabel;
    UILabel         *taxdetails;
    UITextField     *dayNumberInWeek;
    UITextField     *commentsForWeek;
}

    @property (nonatomic ,retain) IBOutlet UILabel      *textlabel;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel      *taxdetails;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField  *dayNumberInWeek;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField  *commentsForWeek;


@end
```

WeekViewTableCell.m:

```
import "WeekViewTableCell.h"


    @implementation WeekViewTableCell
    @synthesize textlabel;
    @synthesize taxdetails;
    @synthesize dayNumberInWeek;
    @synthesize commentsForWeek;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [textlabel release];
    [taxdetails release];
    [dayNumberInWeek release];
    [commentsForWeek release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

DataSource:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"WeekViewCell";  
WeekViewTableCell *cell = (WeekViewTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    [self.appCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

    cell = weekTableViewCell;       
    self.weekTableViewCell = nil;
}

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {

                cell.dayNumberInWeek.hidden = YES;
                cell.commentsForWeek.hidden = YES;
                self.tableView.rowHeight = CELL_ROW_HEIGHT;
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
                cell.taxdetails.tag = 1;

                if (indexPath.row == 0)
                {   
                    cell.textlabel.text = @"Week Day";

                    if (isDoneSelected == YES) 
                        cell.taxdetails.text = [self dateFormatStyle:[uniqueDays objectAtIndex:6]];

                    else 
                        cell.taxdetails.text = [DaysOfCurrentWeek newDateString:[DaysOfCurrentWeek getDayOfCurrentWeek:_kSaturday]];
                }
            }
}
```

I want to persist text/data in textfields in a custom uitableviewcell in a view which has again 3 sections. Every time scroll up/down the data/text disappears, I know the the problem.
But again if someone kindly post some sample/example code that would be really helpful, as am struggling now for a long time.

thanks.

Comment: that's my typical custom uitableviewcell class with properties declared through a bit err read.

Comment: even though i ve created a singleton class and saves the data there, and when tries to update the textfield text/data after every scroll, the textfield never populates with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function.

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WeekViewCell_%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];  
WeekViewTableCell *cell = (WeekViewTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Let me know if you still have the same issue

Comment: I changed it, but still I got the same problem.